# Bundler: `initialize': Read-only file system Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, virtualbox, bundler, gemfile.lock

I'm running `bundle install` in a VM for an application in Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.0.20, Bundler 1.6.2, but it gives me this error about the gemfile.lock

I guess that Bundler is using the global gems, but I need it to use strictly the versions from the gemfile.

I've tried with the few solutions that I've found, but it's the same. If somebody has any suggestion about it.

Comment: Regenerate Gemfile.lock. It seems like it was
out of sync with the Gemfile.

Comment: I tried to regenerate it, but it's still the same. When I run it in my local machine, it works, but it doesn't happen the same in the VM, which it's weird, because my local machine and the VMs share the project's folder.

Comment: "If somebody has any suggestion about"--The sentence is not completed.

Comment: Well, I've completed it now.

Comment: Permissions issue? How have you installed ruby? Via `sudo`? Don't; use `rbenv` or `rvm` and install it as the local user.

Comment: Yes, I use rvm and I've configured the permissions for the VMs. I have different versions of Ruby and it seems that Bundler is installing global gems, not only the ones from the gemfile, even when I set Ruby 1.9.3 with rvm. I don't know how to specify Bundler that only install those ones.